# Serializing multiple streams .NET

Tags: .net, sockets, serialization

I need to be able to send a file + meta-data to a service on another computer and this service should do an operation on the data and return multiple files + meta-data.

The problem is that the files sometimes are very large so it is not feasible to allocate memory to hold the file(s) and associated meta-data at either the client or the server.

I am wondering if there are any libraries out there which can include file streams and other data, combine them to a single stream to be able to stream them over the network.

My best solution so far would be to first send the serialized meta-data including file lengths, and then append the different file streams to that stream and then deconstruct the stream on the other end. Hopefully there is a more elegant way to solve this?

I guess I am looking for something like BinaryFormatter that has support for serialization of the content of the streams that I wish to Serialize.

Answer (score 0):

My networking library can send very large streams without a problem. And it can do it quite fast too (the current HTTP server implementation handles 2700 requests per second on my computer).

You just tell the library to send a stream and it'll do it using chunks.

Check the HTTP server sample since it does just that for the body: https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.networking/blob/master/Source/Protocols/Http/Griffin.Networking.Protocol.Http/HttpService.cs

The `Context.Send(message.Body);` line will send the stream (`FileStream` or whatever)